# ActionCable: One channel per user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am working on notifications for my rails app. There is User model and controller and Like model associated to User with a User has many Likes association.

The idea is, if a user likes the profile of another user, owner of the profile will get a live notification.

This is my app for understanding ActionCable. I studied the [cable api](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/), pub-sub was new to me. I was able to make successful communication through a single channel, and also successfully used the [authorization](https://github.com/rails/actioncable/blob/02238/README.md#a-full-stack-example). But, still I don't understand how to use single channel per user (dynamically generated channel), so that message posted to one user doesn't go to another user.

Is dynamic channel possible?

Or, are there other ways where a single channel satisfies all the users needs

Comment: _Dynamically generated channel_? What you mean? Separate connection to any users?

Comment: @Зелёный I just thought if there's any standard way to do that. In `ApplicationCable::Channel` it is possible to provide generated channel names with string interpolation like this `stream_from "x_channel_#{user_id}"` , also for broadcasting `ActionCable.server.broadcast "x_channel_#{user_id}", message: "Received"`

Comment: @Зелёный yes, separate connection for each user

Comment: separate connection - that not a good practice.

Comment: @Зелёный Please provide a way

Comment: Your question is probably too broad. There is a lot of tutorials  which you can find in google.

Comment: @Зелёный I didn't find the answer that's why I questioned. okay, how can it be shortened?

Comment: Read before [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 6):

The solution was actually simple, but some new terms introduced in ActionCable made it confusing. By the way, here's how I solved it.

I used a single channel but multiple streams for different users.
Here's the ActionCable [documentation link](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#example-2-receiving-new-web-notifications) that clearly states a very identical scenario. I went through the documentation earlier, but somehow I didn't understand it at the first glance.

Sorry for not providing any direct code, I think the documentation will explain it totally.