# I am trying to create chat between two friends in rails 5 using action cable but the message is viewed by all users which in either friends or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In the channel

> javascripts/channel/message.js

```
App.message = App.cable.subscriptions.create('MessageChannel', {  
  received: function(data) {

    return $('#messages').append(this.renderMessage(data));
  },
  renderMessage: function(data) {
    return "<p> <b>" + data.message + "</p>";
  }
});
```

> Routes

```
  post 'messages/chat_create/:friendship_id/:friend_id' =>'messages#chat_create' , as:"chat_create"
```

My Chatcontroller

> class MessagesController < ApplicationController

```
def chat_create

        @chat = current_user.messages.new(msg: params[:message][:msg],friend_id:params[:friend_id])


        if @chat.save
            ActionCable.server.broadcast 'message_channel',message: @chat.msg
            redirect_to chat_path(params[:friendship_id])
        end
    end
```

> messages/chat.html.erb

```
<div id="messages">

<%=form_for :message, url: chat_create_path(params[:friendship_id],params[:friend_id]) , method: :post  do |f|%>
<%=f.text_field :msg %>
<%=f.submit%>
<%end%>

</div>
```

> How can I Improve this Please Provide me solutions

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317317/actioncable-one-channel-per-user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317317/actioncable-one-channel-per-user)

Comment: I followed your given link but this is not working. @maxpleaner

Comment: This isn't a super simple problem you're facing. Probably not going to be a cut-and-paste solution. I'm sure people would be willing to help if you update your question with your latest attempt.

Answer (score 1):

The Channel, Connection and Subscriptions model of ActionCable IIUC is on one Connection multiple Channels can be broadcasted but the User only sees data sent on Subscribed channels only.

Therefore if you want to create chat between two friends, its akin to creating a private Channel, so in your `chat_create` method you can try this

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast "message_channel_#{current_user.id}_#{params[:friend_id]}"
```

basically you want to broadcast on a private Channel. Obviously for this to work you will have to Subscribe both users/friends to the same private channel.